# How to handle a jquery Treeview event inside an angular 8 component class?

Tags: jquery, angular

Every I've found so far suggest that to use jQuery in my angular 8 application, I need to define a global variable `$` as `any`.

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'uis-add-department',
  templateUrl: './add-department.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-department.component.scss']
})
export class AddDepartmentComponent implements OnInit {

  initializeTreeViewWidget(tvData: TreeviewItem[]) {
  $(function () {
    const treeview = $('#treeview-searchable').treeview({
      data: tvData,
      onNodeSelected: function (event, node) {  
        this.displayValue(); 
        this.parentItem = { id: node.id, text: node.text };
        this.displayValue();        
     },
     onNodeUnselected: function (event, node) {
       console.log(`${node.id} was unselected`);
     }
    });
   });
  }

 displayValue(){
   console.log(`parentItem: ${this.parentItem}`);
 }
}
```

When either of 2 events fires, I'm getting the error shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

So far I didn't find an example where it shows how to handle a jQuery event.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Not sure where you've been reading, but jQuery and Angular ideally should not be mixed.

Comment: Can you check if you have included jQuery as CDN in index.html or have you installed it through npm(see if jQuery is included in package.json)?

Answer (score 0):

As Rory said don't use Jquery with Angular

Use [Angular Material Tree](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview) instead [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nqgkneandov?file=app%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts) . More Examples on [documentation page](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples)

Comment: I bought a template which has many features relying on jQury.

Comment: then isolate the Jquery and Angular part in HTML , dont use Jquery inside Angular, however you can use Angular inside Jquery

Comment: Do you mean I need to create a function below the class and handle the event there? All I'm trying to do is just respond to an event. For instance, if an item is selected, add its `id` in an array.